# No adapter attached; skipping layout for recycler view inside material dialog

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialog

I am using the `material-dialogs` library to display a list but the items are not showing up.

I have a `BaseActivity` that is extended by several classes. I have a side menu built using `MaterialDrawer`. When the other selects the `Setup Printer` menu item I want to open up a `material-dialog` that shows a list of printers.

BaseActivity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
    private Drawer result = null;
    Printer mPrinter = null;
    private List<PrinterModel> mPrinters;

protected void setupToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) { ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); }

    new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).build();

    headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withCompactStyle(true)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.logo)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();


    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.side_menu_title_settings),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.side_menu_0_printer).withIcon(R.drawable.fire_smoke).withIdentifier(R.integer.side_menu_0_printer),
                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName("Settings"),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName("tWO").withIcon(R.drawable.fire)
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    int item = (int) drawerItem.getIdentifier();
                    switch (item) {
                        case R.integer.side_menu_0_printer:
                            onSelectPrinter();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    System.out.println("DRAWER " + drawerItem.getIdentifier());
                    if (drawerItem != null && drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1) {
                        //startSupportActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());
                    }

                    if (drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {

                    }

                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();
}


protected void onSelectPrinter() {

    PrinterModel printer = new PrinterModel("TESTDASDASD", "ASDJASLDKJASDASDASD");
    mPrinters = new ArrayList<>();
    mPrinters.add(0, printer);
    mPrinters.add(1, printer);
    mPrinters.add(2, printer);
    mPrinters.add(3, printer);

    SetupPrinterAdapter adapter = new SetupPrinterAdapter(mPrinters);
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.test,null);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    //LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    MaterialDialog dialog =
                    new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .title(R.string.title_printer_setup)
                    .customView(R.layout.test, false)
                    .negativeText(android.R.string.cancel)
                    .build();

    RecyclerView rv = view.findViewById(R.id.rvSetupPrinter2);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    System.out.println("TEST" + adapter.getItemCount()); 
    dialog.show();
}
```

MainActivity (calls setupToolbar() from BaseActivity)

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory(getLayoutInflater(), new IconicsLayoutInflater(getDelegate()));
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mContext = this;
        setupToolbar();
    }
}
```

SetupPrinterAdapter

```
package com.app.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class SetupPrinterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SetupPrinterAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvPrinterName;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvPrinterName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrinterName);
        }
    }

    private List<PrinterModel> mPrinterModels;

    public SetupPrinterAdapter(List<PrinterModel> printers) {
        System.out.println("TEST " + printers.get(0).getName());

        mPrinterModels = printers;
    }

    @Override
    public SetupPrinterAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View rv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_select_printer, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(rv);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SetupPrinterAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        PrinterModel printer = mPrinterModels.get(position);
        TextView mPrinterName = viewHolder.tvPrinterName;
        mPrinterName.setText(printer.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPrinterModels.size();
    }
}
```

TestLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvSetupPrinter2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

rv_select_printer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#80000000"

        android:id="@+id/tvPrinterName"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is,

a) Currently material dialog has it's own layout with

`.customView(R.layout.test, false)`

and you also have your own layout from which you are initializing `RecyclerView`

```
RecyclerView rv = view.findViewById(R.id.rvSetupPrinter2);
```

so as per point `a`, `view` has no connection with `MaterialDialog` and recyclerview is not being displayed.

Solution: Link `view` with material dialog as

```
MaterialDialog dialog =
                new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                .title(R.string.title_printer_setup)
                .customView(view, false)
                //          ^^^ use view
                .negativeText(android.R.string.cancel)
                .build();
```

Or a better solution is to remove `view` as

```
protected void onSelectPrinter() {

    PrinterModel printer = new PrinterModel("TESTDASDASD", "ASDJASLDKJASDASDASD");
    mPrinters = new ArrayList<>();
    mPrinters.add(0, printer);
    mPrinters.add(1, printer);
    mPrinters.add(2, printer);
    mPrinters.add(3, printer);

    SetupPrinterAdapter adapter = new SetupPrinterAdapter(mPrinters);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    //LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    MaterialDialog dialog =
                    new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .title(R.string.title_printer_setup)
                    .customView(R.layout.test, false)
                    .negativeText(android.R.string.cancel)
                    .build();

    RecyclerView rv = dialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.rvSetupPrinter2);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("TEST" + adapter.getItemCount()); 
    dialog.show();
}
```